# Excel: mother-child

Tags: excel

imagine column C1 and C2:

```
C1      C2       C3 = Result
AYX     TEST     TEST
BXD              TEST
DSA              TEST
DAS              TEST
ADS     TEST2    TEST2
SAD              TEST2
ASD     TEST3    TEST3
DDD              TEST3
```

I am failing in creating some Excel code to get the result shown in colunm 3.

Comment: what have you tired?  Post your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
=IF(B2<>"",B2, C1)
```

So you look to the left, if something is there, grab it; if not, grab from the row right above.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like a simple `IF()`, so something like (assuming formatted as a table, formula for row 2)

```
=IF([@C2]="",C1,[@C2])
```